# what to addEventListener to when listening for custom events?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, addeventlistener, dispatchevent

I am sending an event when an sql query returns no matches so that I can continue with the addition to the database.. It seems like actionscript is requiring that I attach the listener to something, but I don't really have any variables that seem like logical candidates at the point where I am in my code.

I just want to listen for the isNewRecord event to be called so that I can then run the insert query; right now it's saying call to possibly undefined method for addEventListern and for dispatchEvent

```
public function addBG(BG:Number, datetime:String, batch:Boolean = false):void{
        checkRecord('Gb', datetime, matchRecord);

        addEventListener("isNewRecord", recordExists);

        function recordExists()
        {/*code to execute query*/}

public function matchRecord(result:SQLResult):void {
        var match:String = result.data[0];
        if (match == null) {
            var allClear:Event = new Event("isNewRecord");
            dispatchEvent(allClear);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is buggy. You have a function within a function.

Also, is your code extending EventDispatcher class (or any class that extends it, like Sprite, MovieClip, etc.?) Make sure it is.

Try this:

```
public function addBG(BG:Number, datetime:String, batch:Boolean = false):void
{
        // note, you're adding this event listener EVERY TIME you call the 
        // addBG function, so make sure you remove it OR add it somewhere in the
        // init or complete functions

        addEventListener("isNewRecord", recordExists);
        checkRecord('Gb', datetime, matchRecord);    
}
public function recordExists():void
{/*code to execute query*/}

public function matchRecord(result:SQLResult):void {
        var match:String = result.data[0];
        if (match == null) {
            var allClear:Event = new Event("isNewRecord");
            dispatchEvent(allClear);
        }
}
```

Comment: my issue is that I'm trying to make a sort of database model, with an 'add' function for each type of data; but I need to verify that it's not already there, which requires going outside of that function w/ sqlresult.. I thought it would be better practice not to make all the parameters class properties. maybe that's what i'll have to do...  and no it doesn't extend event dispatcher because that didn't make sense semantically, but I guess that's why the add/Dispatch Events are not working? the same code works directly in an mxml file though.

Comment: Yes, you need to either have an EventDispatcher object OR make the class extend EventDispatcher in order to use addEventListener / dispatchEvent methods... So semantically it DOES make sense. You should put the "addEventListener" method above the "checkRecord" too. That was my bad and I edited my code. That's fine for the Model object to check the database and to throw an Exception or some sort of logic to handle an already existing result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use events. Your processing of the SQLResult seems synchronous, there is no latency due to any interaction with the user, the server or anything that may take some time.

When Flash executes your code it does the folowing:

```
checkRecord('Gb', datetime, matchRecord);
//then
var match:String = result.data[0];
if (match == null) {
    var allClear:Event = new Event("isNewRecord");
    dispatchEvent(allClear);
}
//and finally
addEventListener("isNewRecord", recordExists);
```

The event is dispatched before the listener is added. 
Here is what you should do:

```
public function addBG(BG:Number, datetime:String, batch:Boolean = false):void
{
        if (checkRecord('Gb', datetime, matchRecord))
        {
            recordExists();
        }
}

public function recordExists():void
{/*code to execute query*/}

public function matchRecord(result:SQLResult):Boolean{
        var match:String = result.data[0];
        if (match == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: The problem is, matchRecord is being called as an SQLResult Event or a callbakcListener function. I was trying to return a boolean, but since the functions are called from listeners, I didn't see how to get the return out from it.  the issue with the event listener explains partially why it wasn't working, can't believe I missed that!